# Amazon AWS Android- DynamoDBHashKey annotation found in class

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to do a simple write operation onto my DynamoDB but looks like it is not as simple as I thought it would be. I seem to be stuck with this error and I am out of solutions. Help needed.

I have the below code where I am trying to write data to AWS DynamoDB

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBIndexHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBIndexRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Identity Pool ID", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions // Region
        );

        WriteToDBOperation wtd=new WriteToDBOperation();
        wtd.execute();
    }

    private class WriteToDBOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    //AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

                    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1) // CRUCIAL
                            .createClient(
                                    AmazonDynamoDBClient.class,
                                    credentialsProvider,
                                    new ClientConfiguration()
                            );


                    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);


                    SongRequest song = new SongRequest();
                    song.setSongID("Test1");
                    song.setSongName("TestSong");
                    mapper.save(book);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error",e.toString());
                }
            return "Done";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv1.setText("Working?");
        }
    }


    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "test1")
    public class SongRequest {
        private String SongName;
        private String SongArtist;
        private String SongAlbum;
        private String SongID;

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id1")
        public void setSongID(String songid) {
            this.SongID = songid;
        }

        public String getSongID() {
            return SongID;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "testt12")
        public String getSongName() {
            return SongName;
        }

        public void setSongName(String songname) {
            this.SongName = songname;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the below mentioned error and eventually the write operation does not happen.

```
02-07 16:26:30.308 22309-22309/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-07 16:26:30.577 22309-22309/amazonaws.amazonawstest D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
02-07 16:26:30.577 22309-22309/amazonaws.amazonawstest D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
02-07 16:26:30.611 22309-22344/amazonaws.amazonawstest D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
02-07 16:26:30.618 22309-22309/amazonaws.amazonawstest D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-07 16:26:30.621 22309-22343/amazonaws.amazonawstest E/Error: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: No interface com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey annotation found in class class amazonaws.amazonawstest.MainActivity$SongRequest
02-07 16:26:30.661 22309-22344/amazonaws.amazonawstest I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
02-07 16:26:30.662 22309-22344/amazonaws.amazonawstest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 16:26:30.683 22309-22344/amazonaws.amazonawstest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

The solution that I have already done and does not work for me are in the below links

[Android Amazon DynamoDb error in basic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556023/android-amazon-dynamodb-error-in-basic-action][1])

Any other ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the mapper. It complains about a POJO which doesn't have a property annotated as DynamoDBHashKey. The annotation is needed by mapper to extract information out of POJO. Clearly you have it annotated. One possible cause is that you have proguard turned on. Please configure it to keep annotations.

> If your application, applet, servlet, library, etc., uses annotations, you may want to preserve them in the processed output. Annotations are represented by attributes that have no direct effect on the execution of the code. However, their values can be retrieved through introspection, allowing developers to adapt the execution behavior accordingly. By default, ProGuard treats annotation attributes as optional, and removes them in the obfuscation step. If they are required, you'll have to specify this explicitly:
>
> -keepattributes *Annotation*

For more information, please refer to [Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not map the fields properly and hence got this error. Resolved it now.